# Twig - rendering some variables(constant)?

Tags: php, twig

I need some variables(constant) in my project:

path_to_root
path_to_images

I would like to make it without php, just Twig, so i create main.twig:

```
main.twig:

{% set path_to_root = "/some_folder" %}
{% set path_to_images = "/some_images" %}
```

In second template i extends by main.twig, so

```
template.twig

{% extends "main.twig" %}

{% block some_block %}
<a href="{{ path_to_root }}/link.php">some_text</a>
<img src="{{ path_to_images }}/image.png" />
{% endblock %}
```

Yes, it works, bu my question:
Is this good way for having main.twig and in child extends with main?
In each file of templates will i must extends with main.twig?

Sorry for my english :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about other php files but the images should go in the assets folder which then you can import using

```
<img src="{{ asset('path/to/folder/image.png') }}" />
```

Comment: But must i declarate path or import with php?

Comment: @Mati you just put your image inside that folder and call it using asset. no need to import or declare anything.

Comment: But when I have many folders with images and i want to choose one of them dependency of user template? Path will be change dependency of users